# Writing $e^A$ as an expression of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

Let $A\in\mathscr{L}(x)$ and satisfies the condition $A^2=A$.

Write the function $e^A$ as expression of A.

My attempt:

Let's start with $e^x$, which we  re-write as a series:

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\bigg(\frac{1}{n!}\bigg)x^n$$.

Here $$\bigg(\frac{1}{n!}\bigg)=a_{n}$$, so we get

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\bigg(a_n\bigg)x^n$$

Since we have a that $A$ is a diagonizable matrix, we have the following.  Suppose $P^{-1}AP=D=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$. The given function $f(x)=e^x$, we can define in terms of A as $$f(A) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{(\lambda_1)} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & e^{(\lambda_2)} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & e^{(\lambda_n)} \end{pmatrix}$$.

But to me, this seems odd, since $e=\sum\frac{1}{n!}$, so shouldn't the right answer be:

$$f(A) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{1!}^{x} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2!}^{x} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & \frac{1}{n!}^{x} \end{pmatrix}$$.

Maybe I am confusing the matrix with the variable x here, but the first matrix doesn't seem to give the full answer.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Using a diagonlization of $A$ is not necessary. As you said, $\mathrm{exp}(A) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} A^k$, now consider what each $A^k$ is and how this infinite sum simplifies.

Comment: Note that $A^3=AA^2=AA=A^2=A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with $e^x$, which we  re-write as a series:

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\bigg(\frac{1}{j!}\bigg)x^j$$.

Therefore,

$$f(A) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\bigg(\frac{1}{j!}\bigg)A^j$$.

Given that $A^2=A$,

$$f(A) = I +  \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\frac{A^{j}}{j!}= I +  A\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\frac{A^{j-1}}{j!}=  I +  A\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j!}=  I + A\left( \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1}{j!}-1\right)= I +  A(e-1)$$

Comment: You miss the exponent symbol in the end

Comment: This is not correct. For $A = 0$ this suggests that $\mathrm{exp}(0) = 0$, which is not correct. Rather, we have $\exp(A) = \operatorname{id} + A(e-1)$ as $A^k = A$ only for $k\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

First at all we need to admit a known result which is that the function $f(x)=e^x$   operates on the algebra of $A's$ (matrices) (for example $f(x)=\sqrt{ x^2+3}$ does not operate i.e. $f(A)=\sqrt{A^2+3}$ can have no sens). Then
$$f(A)=\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\bigg(\frac{1}{n!}\bigg)\right)A^n$$ and because clearly $A^n=A$ we have $$f(A)=I+\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(\frac{1}{n!}\bigg)\right)A$$